# How do I create a new column and add text that is specific to each row in R studio?

Tags: r

I'm new to R Studio and am learning about dataframes.
I'm trying to add the new column "uniqueID" to my dataframe "Populations" with unique values for each row in this new column. No problem, I can append a new column like this: `Populations$uniqueID`

However I'm having trouble adding unique values to each row under this new column. The values should be a combination of the values in each row from the existing columns "location", "variant", and "time". So, for each row the value for the new column uniqueID should be something like "LocationVariantTime" (e.g. "CaliforniaMedium1953"). Here's the code I'm trying, using `paste()`, but it's definitely wrong. I need to figure out how to grab the values for each row.

`Populations$uniqueID <- paste(Populations$location, Populations$variant, Populations$time)`

Here's the output when I view the dataframe. There is no new column with data: https://share.getcloudapp.com/7Kuykdg4

The error that I get reads:

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, uniqueID, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 280932

Thank you in advance for helping someone who is learning,

Comment: You may consider expanding your question with example of your data and output you are getting and output you are expecting to get. I don't see a problem with your current solution `d <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y=c("A","B","C"))
d$a <- paste0(d$x, d$y)` as it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Thank you, here's an example  of the output I am getting, but as you can see there is no new column with text data. Any ideas on how I can adjust my code to include the values in a new column? https://share.getcloudapp.com/7Kuykdg4
The error that I get reads:

Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, uniqueID, value = character(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 280932

I appreciate it!

Comment: Try to check your code for typos etc. As you can see in my example above your code should work. Try to save result of `paste` somewhere else and see what it is. From the error it should be character(0), which  doest not make much sense. Try following `Population$uniqueID <- rnorm(nrow(Population))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the output the names of the columns are uppercase:

```
Populations$uniqueID <- paste(Populations$Location, Populations$Variant, Populations$Time)
```

The solution? A simple case change! Thank's everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem far off. You might have to convert the values in `paste()` to character first though, like this:

```
Populations$uniqueID <- paste(as.character(Populations$location), as.character(Populations$variant), as.character(Populations$time), sep = "")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the code you posted and got this error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, uniqueID, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 2809321

Answer (score 0):

You could row-wise `apply` `paste` on the id columns.

## Example

```
dat <- transform(dat, un.id=apply(dat[1:3], 1, paste, collapse=""))
head(dat)
#   id    type year      value        un.id
# 1  A Mmedium 2018  1.3709584 AMmedium2018
# 2  B Mmedium 2018 -0.5646982 BMmedium2018
# 3  C Mmedium 2018  0.3631284 CMmedium2018
# 4  A   Large 2018  0.6328626   ALarge2018
# 5  B   Large 2018  0.4042683   BLarge2018
# 6  C   Large 2018 -0.1061245   CLarge2018
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- cbind(expand.grid(id=LETTERS[1:3], 
                         type=c("Mmedium", "Large"), 
                         year=2018:2020), value=rnorm(18))
```

Comment: Thank you, would you recommend I change dat to the dataframe Populations?

Comment: Yeah sure, just replace `dat` with `populations`, and replace variable names of course.